# Do table hints in the view definition affect the view?

Tags: sql-server, view, hint

We know that we can use table hints when selecting records in our own queries.

my question is:

when we create a view and use table hints such as "Nolock", "Holdlock", etc ...
and then save the view in SQL server, does the table hint we used affect the view?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any hints in the view affect how it's used.

Note: a table hint on a view propagates as well

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WITH (NOLOCK)-- hint applies to base tables too
```

Comment: even if we have gathered records from other server and other DB?

Comment: With linked servers etc? Sorry, I don't know. Other DBs on the same server: probably yes